# Can we ignore htaccess rewrite rules for a particular domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For Now I have written following rewrite condition and rules in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/ -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want these rule should not work for particular domain e.g. www.example.com.
  Can we do this or any other option to achieve this?

Comment: Its not resolving my problem, above rules mapped with document root.So every domain mapped with document root to its corresponding domain name e.g. http://example.com mapped with "example" document root.I need to ignore these rules for a particular domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want these rule should not work for particular domain e.g. `www.example.com`

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine on` line:

```
# ignore all the rules for www.example.com domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```